# MySQL erroring out on one field in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this pre-existing table structure (yes data and time are terrible names but they are already there):
[image]

However everything grinds to a halt on updating the in/out field.
(Also tried with prepared statements: no luck)

This does not work:

```
$update_punch = $conn->query("UPDATE ttime SET date='$the_edited_date_w_mysql', time='$the_edited_time', inout='$the_ins_and_outs' WHERE id='$the_id' LIMIT 1");
```

The first line of this works but it chokes on the 2nd (chocks with inout being a var or 'in':

```
$update_punch = $conn->query("UPDATE ttime SET date='$the_edited_date_w_mysql', time='$the_edited_time' WHERE id='$the_id' LIMIT 1");   
$update_punch = $conn->query("UPDATE ttime SET inout='$the_ins_and_outs' WHERE id='$the_id' LIMIT 1");
```

Here is there error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inout='out' WHERE id='171366' LIMIT 1' at line 1' in /site/updatepunchesbystore2.php:43 Stack trace: #0 /site/updatepunchesbystore2.php(43): PDO->query('UPDATE ttime SE...') #1 {main} thrown in /site/updatepunchesbystore2.php on line 43
```

I have fought with it for an hour and I'm stumped!

Any thoughts?

Comment: **A:** `inout` is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html (made up of two words, `in` and `out` both being reserved words also). Wrap that word in backticks or use another name.

Comment: what is the value of `$the_ins_and_outs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the keywords in backticks

```
`inout`='$the_edited_time'
```

should work for you

Comment: This did it...I worried so much about date and time that it never occured to me that inout could be a reserved word in MySQL.  Backticks fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$qry= "UPDATE ttime SET `inout`='{$the_ins_and_outs}' WHERE id='$the_id'";
$update_punch = $conn->query($qry);
```